# Is it possible to send a response back to the client from server actions in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, server-action

I am working on a Next.js application and I have defined an action under `app/actions/create-foo-action.js`. I am trying to send a response back to the client from this server action.

```js
import { connectDB } from "@utils/database"
import { User } from "@models/user"

export const createFoo = async (foo) => {
  try {
    await connectDB();
    await User.create(foo);
    res.send({title: "OK"}); // Is this possible?
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({title: "Error"}); // Is this possible?
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it in Next.js. Is it possible to send a response back to the client from server actions like this? If not, what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: You have to use useFormState (in the future called useActionState) to return data from a server action. https://www.robinwieruch.de/next-forms/

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a response from a server action per-se but you can return a value from it. Please note that server actions are now a stable feature in Next.js and can be used in production, using an API endpoint is still a valid option too.

```js
import { User } from "@models/user";
import { connectDB } from "@utils/database";

export async function myAction(foo) {
  "use server"; // mark function as server action
  try {
    await connectDB();
    await User.create(foo);
    return { title: "OK" };
  } catch (err) {
    return { title: "Error" };
  }
}
```

In you client component you can then simply call the function and await the result of the server action as seen in the example below:

```
"use client";

import { useCallback } from "react";
import { myAction } "from/where-ever";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const onClick = useCallback(async () => {
    const { title } = await myAction({ name: "John Doe" });
    console.log(title);
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Create John Doe</button>;
};
```

You can find more about server actions inside the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions). If you want to use an API in combination with a client side fetch, here are [some resources to get you started](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [useFormState](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState).
You can find examples in the React documentation and Next.js documentation:

- [React doc - (Using information returned by a form action)](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState#using-information-returned-by-a-form-action)
- [Next.js doc - (Error Handling)](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have this action:

```
export async function createBlog(
  formData: FormData
) {
  const title = formData.get("title");
  const body = formData.get("body");
  // validation check
  if (typeof title !== "string" || title.length < 5) {
    return {
      message: "Title must be longer than 5 chars",
    };
  }
  if (typeof body !== "string" || body.length < 20) {
    return {
      message: "body must be longer than 20 chars",
    };
  }
  // if you do not handle this, your app will crash
  try{
  // talk to db
  } catch(err){
  if (err instanceof Error){
     return {message:err.message}
  } else {
       return {
               message:"Generic Error Message"
       }
      }
  }
  

  redirect("/");
}
```

If validation does not pass, return the message to the user

```
import {useFormState} from 'react-dom'
```

since we are using hook, our component must be a client component

```
'use client'

export default function Page(){
   // action is kinda enhanced version of 
   // we are returning the an object with message key. set the initial
   const [formState,action]=useFormState(yourAction,{message:""})
   
   <form action={action} >
   </form>
   // if validation does not pass, display the message here
   {formState.message ? (
         <div >
            {formState.message}
          </div>
          ) : null}
}
```